# how can i set a dynamic height to collection view cell in swift?

Tags: swift, layout, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

HI everyone i'm looking for a working method that allows to dynamically set the height in my collectionViewCell because I tried various other answers without success.

My situation is pretty simple, I have a cell with an image, a UIlabel that displays username and a UILabel which contains some text. It's a common Comment cell for a post. [My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it0L2.png)

I tried this method but it doesn't work precisely because the height is too much compared to what is necessary

```
private func estimatedFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 270, height: 80)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)], context: nil)
}
```

so my question is: there is a correct way to implement dynamic size on collection view cell like layout attribute **wrap_content** for Android?

Comment: Why you want to set dynamic height. Do not provide any height to your cell and make number of lines of `UILabel` to 0. Then your cell will automatically manage the height according to the data provided.

Comment: @AmanGupta i tried your method in two different ways: with collection view estimatiedSize set to none, which without any height does not show anything; and i have tried with estimatedSize set to automatic which completely destroys the cell layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem using constraints and Automatic Estimated Size on Collection View. Setting up all constraints I forced the width of LABEl to be equal to the cell width and for the height I set the top and bottom spacing for the UILabel (with lines 0) to be equal to its content view (the one standard for the UiCollectionViewCell)

**IT'S also important to set the size of the collection view cell to automatic**
[VIEW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WPOT.png)